# How can I make my GCP Workflow keep looping when encountering a 404 error?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, workflow

I'm working on a GCP Workflow and running into a problem – the loop stops when I hit a 404 error. I've tried checking out the GCP docs, but no luck so far. Any ideas on how to make the loop keep going, even when it hits a 404 error?

The second part: `SendNotification`, that returns the 404 error.

My GCP syntax is this:

```
main:
  steps:
    - getOnboardingPersons:
        call: http.get
        args:
          url: ${sys.get_env("SERVER_URL") + "/GetPersonIds"}
          auth: 
            type: OIDC
        result: personsForOnboardingEvents
    - loopThroughResults:      
        try:
          for:
            value: onboardingPayload
            index: idx
            in: ${personsForOnboardingEvents.body}
            steps:
              - sendNotification:
                  call: SendNotification
                  args:
                    personIds: ${onboardingPayload.personIds}
                    notificationEvent: ${onboardingPayload.notificationEvent}
        except:
          as: e
          steps:
            - TypeError:
                return: "No person ids found in personsForOnboardingEvents."
            - known_errors:
                switch:
                  - condition: ${e.code == 404}
                    return: ${e.body}
            - unhandled_exception:
                return: ${e.message}
    - theEnd:
        return: ${personsForOnboardingEvents}

SendNotification:
    params: [personIds, notificationEvent]
    steps:
      - loop:
          try:
            for:
              value: personId
              index: idx
              in: ${personIds}
              steps:
                - httpCall:
                      call: http.post
                      args:
                        url: ${sys.get_env("SERVER_URL") + "/SendByPersonId"}
                        auth: 
                          type: OIDC
                        body:
                          PersonId: ${personId}
                          NotificationEventName: ${notificationEvent}
                      result: httpResult
          except:
            as: e
            steps:
              - unhandled_exception:
                  return: ${e.body}
```

**personsForOnboardingEvents** - is a list of personids to each event:

```
[
  {
    "personIds": [],
    "notificationEvent": "EventA"
  },
  {
    "personIds": [],
    "notificationEvent": "EventB"
  },
  {
    "personIds": [],
    "notificationEvent": "EventC"
  },
]
```

### UPDATE

right, fixed it, but still I am looping through ids, then when any id return 404 it stops the loop:

```
SendNotification:
    params: [personIds, notificationEvent]
    steps:
      - loop:
          for:
            value: personId
            index: idx
            in: ${personIds}
            steps:
              - httpCall:
                  try:
                    call: http.post
                    args:
                      url: ${sys.get_env("SERVER_URL") + "/Communication/SendNotificationByPerson"}
                      auth: 
                        type: OIDC
                      body:
                        PersonId: ${personId}
                        NotificationEventName: ${notificationEvent}
                    result: httpResult
                  except:
                    as: e
                    steps:
                      - known_errors:
                          switch:
                          - condition: ${e.code == 404}
                            return: ${e.body}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your try/except is around the for loop. So, the exception is not catch INSIDE the for loop, but outside, and thus the loop is broken.

You must put it in the steps inside the loop for. Like that, you can continue the loop even if you have an exception

```
main:
  steps:
    - getOnboardingPersons:
        call: http.get
        args:
          url: ${sys.get_env("SERVER_URL") + "/GetPersonIds"}
          auth: 
            type: OIDC
        result: personsForOnboardingEvents
    - loopThroughResults:      
        for:
          value: onboardingPayload
          index: idx
          in: ${personsForOnboardingEvents.body}
          steps:
            - sendNotification:
              try:
                call: SendNotification
                args:
                  personIds: ${onboardingPayload.personIds}
                  notificationEvent: ${onboardingPayload.notificationEvent}
              except:
                as: e
                steps:
                 - TypeError:
                     return: "No person ids found in personsForOnboardingEvents."
                 - known_errors:
                     switch:
                       - condition: ${e.code == 404}
                         return: ${e.body}
                 - unhandled_exception:
                     return: ${e.message}
....
```

---

**EDIT 1**

Following your update, you perform a return in your condition. Like in any function, if you perform a return, you go out the function.

You have to do what you want in the condition (log, retry, ...) and then `Continue`

Like this

```
                  except:
                    as: e
                    steps:
                      - known_errors:
                          switch:
                          - condition: ${e.code == 404}
                            next: continue
```

Comment: Oh, right, fixed it, but the problem is inside SendNotification where there is another loop. I did the update, but still didnt handle the exception correctly - check updated answer

Comment: thanks man `next: continue` did the trick